# Multiple scenes using the same group of views and controller functionality, without copy-pasting code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In my app (using swift), I have a scene where the user must input a password using a keypad made up of a conglomeration of buttons. On the first load of the app, I'd also like there to be a scene where the user inputs the password they would like to use for the app.

The password entering screen would use the same button-conglomeration keypad.

In the interest of creating a maintainable code base, I don't want to rewrite code by copy-pasting the xml and controller code of the keypad.

What's the right way to handle this in iOS? Is there a way you can abstract a group of view elements and add them to the storyboard as a single view with some kind of interface?

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented this was as follows:

Create a Container View. Move all of the views in the group to this container view. Create a controller for this container view. Embed this container view inside any view where it is needed.

To have functionality between the parent view and the container view, I created a protocol with the needed functions (for me it was passEntered(pass: String) -> Bool) and had the views using the container conform to that protocol. The container view controller calls the protocol functions on the parent controller when necessary.

So, specifically for my problem: I put the entire passcode keypad in a container view. I then embedded that container view in both the unlock scene and the set passcode scene. The controllers for both of those scenes implemented a ViewWithPasscode protocol, which has the passEntered function. When someone enters all 4 pin values, the keypad controller calls it's parent controller's passEntered function.